# How should Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions be used and what is the difference from window.onload?

Tags: javascript

I've recently stumbled across IIFE's and am intrigued at their purpose.  I understand that they're used to automatically invoke the function, thus removing the need to create a function and calling it when the window loads.  How, though, should they be used correctly?  For instance, this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    console.log("hello");
})
```

Does the same thing as this:

```
(
    function(){
        console.log("Hello");
    }();
)
```

So when should IIFE's be used?  As an additional question.  What is the difference between the two?

Comment: IIFEs and `window.onload` are two *completely* different things. There is no relation between the two of them.

Comment: Perhaps if you put the script tag at the bottom of the body, it might appear that they are executing at the same time, but just because I'm curious, where did you find that they would act the same?

Comment: @4castle just from running these two scripts in a browser.

Comment: Actually your second snippet is a syntax error. The semicolon needs to go after the outer parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **Immediately**-Invoked Function Expression runs, well, immediately.

An event listener or event handler most probably won't.

```js
var foo = "Old value";
(function() {
  console.log("Updating value");
  foo = "Variable has been updated";
})();
console.log(foo); // "Variable has been updated";
```

```js
var foo = "Old value";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log("Updating value, but it's too late");
  foo = "Variable has been updated";
});
console.log(foo); // "Old value";
```

Answer (score 1):

IIFEs are generally used to create a local scope so variables can be used without creating globals (or within a loop so that a variable won't be overwritten on the next iteration).

An IIFE is involved **immediately**. A load handler is involved when the load event fires (after the document, and its dependencies, have loaded).